# Why directive with ng-repeat is compiled out of table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem in this code

```
        <table class="turing-matrix">
            <state ng-repeat="state in mainCtrl.stateMatrix" fields="state.fields" state-name="state.stateName"></state>
        </table>
```

. Why angular compile this out of table ? :
[image]

State directive code:

```
angular.module('turingApp')
.directive('state', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'state.html',
        scope: {
            stateName: '=',
            fields: '='
        },
        link: function() {

        }
    }
});
```

Directive template:

```
<tr>
    <th>{{ stateName }}</th>
    <td>
        <field ng-repeat="field in fields" field="field"></field>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add code for directive, anf how you use it, not links. Also it would be great if you can provide working sample on _plunkr_ or _jsfiddle_

Comment: what browser you use?

Comment: seems problem with browser: you put in _table_ tag not expected element, and browser push-up it, you can reproduce it with simplest code: `<table>
          <asd>123</asd>
          <asd>123</asd>
          <asd>123</asd>
        </table>` here _asd_ elements, also moved from _table_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems problem not in angular, but in how browser process not valid html.

You can reproduce this issue with simplest code

```
<table>
    <asd>123</asd>
    <asd>123</asd>
    <asd>123</asd>
</table>
```

So, here not used angular, but same behavior.

For solving you can turn your directive *restrict* to *A*, and use it as attribute

```
.directive('state', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'state.html',
        scope: {
            stateName: '=',
            fields: '='
        },
        link: function() {
console.log('state',arguments);
        }
    }
})
```

and use it on *tr*

```
<table class="turing-matrix">
  <tr state ng-repeat="state in mainCtrl.stateMatrix" fields="state.fields" state-name="state.stateName"></tr>
</table>
```

**[Sample on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/od464rr986P0QpDb5F6R?p=preview)**